# how i get all items of all users

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I'm practicing some Angular/Ionic and am having a bit of a hard time figuring out how i get all offresList of all users

this is my database look like :

[image]

This is my providre offre.ts

```
export class OffreProvider {

public offreListRef: firebase.database.Reference;

constructor() {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.offreListRef = firebase
          .database()
          .ref(`/userProfile/${user.uid}/offreList`);
      } 
  });
}

 createOffre(
  offreTitre: string,
  offreSecteur: string,
  offreVille: string,
  offreDispo: string,
  offreDescrip: string,
  offreDate : string,
 ): firebase.database.ThenableReference {
 return this.offreListRef.push({
  titre: offreTitre,
  secteur: offreSecteur,
  ville: offreVille,
  dispo: offreDispo,
  descrip: offreDescrip,
  date : offreDate
});
}

getOffreList(): firebase.database.Reference {
return this.offreListRef;
}
}
```

and this is how i get all offres of currentUser
mesOffres.ts

```
  export class MesOffresPage {

  public offreList: Array<any>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, 
 public offreProvider: OffreProvider) {
 }

  creatOffre(): void {
 this.navCtrl.push('CreateOffrePage');
 }

 ionViewDidLoad() {
 this.offreProvider.getOffreList().on("value", offreListSnapshot => {
   this.offreList = [];
   offreListSnapshot.forEach(snap => {
     this.offreList.push({
      id: snap.key,
      titre: snap.val().titre,
      secteur: snap.val().secteur,
      ville: snap.val().ville
      });
     return false;
  });
 });
 }
 }
```

now how i can get all offreslist of all Users with alloffres.ts
and display it in alloffres.html
I m stacking for 2 days

Comment: Can you share what versions of firebase you are using? Also what errors you are getting?

Comment: thanks Mr.Rudenko for your reply, so the code below is correct i don't get any error it display all offers for the current user, Now i wanna display all offres of all users but i have no idea how i do it

Comment: I see I can show you direction but since I don't have access to your exact environment / code you may have to figure out the egdes;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the offers across all users, you will have to load all user data. Something like this:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
  let ref = firebase.database().ref("userProfile");
  ref.on("value", userListSnapshot => {
    this.offreList = [];
    userListSnapshot.forEach(userSnapshot => {
      let offerListSnapshot = userSnapshot.child("offreList");
      offerListSnapshot.forEach(offerSnapshot => {
        this.offreList.push({
          id: snap.key,
          titre: snap.val().titre,
          secteur: snap.val().secteur,
          ville: snap.val().ville
        });
      });
    })
  });
 }
```

Note that this code *also* loads the profile data for each user, which the it doesn't use. This is one of the many reasons why experienced Firebase developers recommend to keep separate entity types in separate top-level lists. So in your case, I'd recommend having:

```
userProfiles: {
  uid1: {
    ...
  },
  uid2: {
    ...
  }
},
userOffers: {
  uid1: {
    "-LRZ...": {
      ...
    }
  },
  uid2: {
    "-LRQ...": {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

With the above structure you can load just the offers for all users with code very similar to what I shared above. But with the updated structure, you won't be loading the user profile data unnecessarily. And just in case you need the profile data and offers for a user, you can easily load both in separate calls. The performance will be very similar, since [Firebase pipelines the requests over a single connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786).

Comment: Hi Mr.Puffelen, Thank you very much for your reply, it so satisfying, but how i can do like this separate entity types, that let me display offres of current user and offers of all users,